# Redirection to (https and non www) for all requested URI via web.config

Tags: azure, web-config

I want ( https and non www) redirection for all requested URI. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks,

It works well for

1) 'http' to 'https' (success)

2) 'https' to 'https' (success)

3) '/index' to '/'

4) '/contact (with www)' to '/contact (with non www)' (unsuccess)

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/" >
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>

        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
                <add key="/index.php" value="/" />
                <add key="/a.php" value="/a" />
                <add key="/Res" value="/results#experience" />
                <add key="/blog/" value="/" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>

        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>                   
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="Remove www prefix">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.com.au/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>

            <rule name="Redirect index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(\w*/)?index\.php" ignoreCase="true"></match>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="test\.com\.au$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.com.au/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>         
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />

    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Tue,19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>

    <defaultDocument> 
        <files> 
        <remove value="index.php" /> 
        <add value="index.php" /> 
        </files> 
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

I want all requested uri to redirect to https and non www via web.config only

Comment: What's the meaning that for all request url? Do you mean for all https://test.com.au/ sub page or other thing?

Comment: https://test.com.au/contact.php

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the code as below:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}"></action>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true"></add>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Also tried with pattern="^www\.example\.com\.au$" , didn't work either. Thanks